# CCSpriteFrameCache not properly retrieving images with '-ipad' suffix

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I made two sets of spritesheets using `TexturePacker`, one is called `objects-0.plist`/`objects0-png` and `objects-0-ipad.plist`/`objects-0-ipad.png`. Each of them has the following images in it:

```
// objects-0.plist / objects-0.png
object-0-0.png : 50x50 PNG file
object-0-1.png : 50x50 PNG file
object-0-2.png : 50x50 PNG file

// objects-0-ipad.plist / objects-0-ipad.png
object-0-0-ipad.png : 100x100 PNG file
object-0-1-ipad.png : 100x100 PNG file
object-0-2-ipad.png : 100x100 PNG file
```

I've loaded these up in the `CCSpriteFrameCache` like so:

```
bool AnimTest::init( ) {
    if ( !CCLayer::init( ) ) return false;

    CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache( ) -> addSpriteFrameWithFile( "objects-0.plist" );
}
```

Then, I tried making a `CCSprite` object using one of the files in the `.plist` file.

```
bool AnimTest::init( ) {
    if ( !CCLayer::init( ) ) return false;

    CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache( ) -> addSpriteFrameWithFile( "objects-0.plist" );

    CCSprite * testSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName( "object-0-0.png" );
    this -> addChild( testSprite );

    return true;
}
```

If I run this one from an iPod/iPhone, it works fine. However, if I run this from an iPad, `CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName( )` throws an `assert` saying the file name is invalid.

However, if I explicitly use the files with the `-ipad` suffix, it works fine with no errors, which it should.

```
bool AnimTest::init( ) {
    if ( !CCLayer::init( ) ) return false;

    CCSpriteFrameCache::sharedSpriteFrameCache( ) -> addSpriteFrameWithFile( "objects-0-ipad.plist" );

    CCSprite * testSprite = CCSprite::createWithSpriteFrameName( "object-0-0-ipad.png" );
    this -> addChild( testSprite );

    return true;
}
```

How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: maybe you need to use some if-else in your code. I have update to 2.0.3, using folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought of an idea while writing the question which I only tested when it was sent and it worked.

The problem is that I'm retrieving the Sprite Frame directly from the file name. Meaning, I'm retrieving `objects-0-0.png` and `cocos2d-x` does not automatically use the suffixed version. So, knowing that, I re-made/re-wrote the `.plist` file so that the two files (one with and one without suffix) have the same image file names, but are totally different images. The `.plist` files and the `.png` spritesheets are left with the suffixes.

Instead of:

```
// objects-0.plist / objects-0.png
object-0-0.png : 50x50 PNG file
object-0-1.png : 50x50 PNG file
object-0-2.png : 50x50 PNG file

// objects-0-ipad.plist / objects-0-ipad.png
object-0-0-ipad.png : 100x100 PNG file
object-0-1-ipad.png : 100x100 PNG file
object-0-2-ipad.png : 100x100 PNG file
```

Rename all the files inside the `.plist` into those that don't use the suffix.

```
// objects-0.plist / objects-0.png
object-0-0.png : 50x50 PNG file
object-0-1.png : 50x50 PNG file
object-0-2.png : 50x50 PNG file

// objects-0-ipad.plist / objects-0-ipad.png
object-0-0.png : 100x100 PNG file
object-0-1.png : 100x100 PNG file
object-0-2.png : 100x100 PNG file
```

Comment: Yup, the suffix is only for actual files. The names of references inside any file, not just texture atlas plists but also tilemaps, bitmap fonts, etc are not following the -hd/-ipad/-ipadhd convention. In this case, the frame name "object-0.0.png" shouldn't really have a .png extension to clarify that, but alas, so goes tradition.

Comment: The `.png` extension was added by TexturePacker int the `.plist` file so I just used those names.

Answer (score 1):

What version of cocos2d-x are you using? Since 2.0.2 version suffixes aren't supported and you should use directories for different devices against suffixes in file names. You can see details [here](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Mechanism_of_loading_resources) and in cocos2dx examples.

Comment: Still using 2.0.1. I didn't bother updating to 2.0.3 since I'm too far down in the project and I fear upgrading might cause inconsistencies and conflicts within the code.